# 2 VPN connections

Tags: vpn

What happens when I connect my phone to VPN1, use the phone's hotspot for my laptop, and connect my laptop to VPN2?

`Laptop --- VPN2 --- Phone --- VPN1`

Is there tunnel in a tunnel or two separate tunnels?

Comment: Are you connecting both to the same VPN ? It's not clear due to your diagram showing vpn1 and vpn2, while the sentence above shows only vpn for both.
When you say you use "hotspot with your laptop" do you mean you connect your phone to your laptop or the other way around, and you connect your laptop to your phone's hotspot?

Comment: I connect my laptop to my phone. The phone is connected to VPN1 server and laptop is connected to VPN2 server

Answer (score 1):

If you laptop is connected to your phone's mobile hotspot, and you have a VPN connection on your laptop and another vpn connection on your phone (being different vpns), then unless your phone is rooted and you configured all the hotspot traffic through the phones vpn, your laptop VPN is just using the hotspot/mobile as origin (and not the phone's vpn).

Hope it's clear, if it's not, comment and I will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To be very clear, let's forget about mobile phones for a second. Let's assume your router is a VPN client of VPN2 and your laptop is a VPN client of VPN1.

```
Laptop --- Router === VPN2 --- VPN1
```

(- indicates single tunnel, = indicates two tunnels)

In this case, there is indeed a VPN within a VPN, at least between your router and its VPN server.

However, as pointed out in @Leo's answer, mobile phone hotspots do not behave in the same way. Hotspot traffic is often routed separately so that wireless carriers can perform separate accounting (e.g. different data cap, different speed limit), and is not affected by a system VPN (although it may depend on specific mobile device and carrier implementations). This results in a slightly different picture:

```
                ---------- VPN2
Laptop --- Phone
                ---------- VPN1
```

So there is never a VPN within a VPN in this scenario .

Just to be sure, I tested this, and you can test it too. With an Android phone connected to a VPN, a hotspot client's traffic *did not* go through the VPN and went directly from the phone to the destination. This can be verified by going to any website that displays your IP address. You will find (with WHOIS) that it belongs to your wireless carrier and not the VPN provider.